# Does the System.out object belong to class System or class PrintStream?

Tags: java, class, system.out

I'm new to programming and I just started learning Java. I'm curious that does the object System.out belong to class System or class PrintStream?

I referred to a textbook, JAVA CONCEPTS 4/e. The textbook states that *to use the out object in the System class, you must refer it as `System.out`* but later in the book it states that the `System.out` belongs to class PrintStream.

I've searched google and stackoverflow but all the answers are too hard for me to understand.

Comment: You could check it via `System.out instanceof PrintStream?System.out.println("Ok, I'm PrintStream"):System.out.println("No, I'm not aPrintStream")`

Comment: Define 'belong to'. It has no meaning in Java. System.out is a *member* of System and it is of *type* PrintStream.

Answer (score 7):

"out" belongs to class "System" and is of type "PrintStream" :)

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you mean by "belongs to".

Usually, people would say `out` "belongs" to `System` because it is a static field declared in that class. Note, though, that this concept of belonging is only a weak one, basically implying only a namespace ownership. There is no special relation between a class and its static fields.

You may also say the object referred to by the `out` variable belongs to the `PrintStream` class because it is an instance of that class (or a subclass), just as "beagle" belongs to the "dog" class.  This is not standard usage in Java parlance, but it makes perfect sense from the perspective of type theory, where a *type* is really a set of values, and the value of `out` "belongs" to that the type / set defined by the `PrintStream` class.

Comment: Community wiki answer?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza See, I liked the idea!

Comment: Great then. By the way, I would remark the last sentence: *There is no special relation between a class and its static fields.*

Answer (score 3):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream` object. It is defined in `System` (so, it is member of `System`) class as :

```
static PrintStream out
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Answer (score 2):

It is **[defined as](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)**:

```
static PrintStream  out
```

Answer (score 2):

`out` is a [static](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable#Static_Variables_as_Class_Variables) field in [System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html). Its type is [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

In loose simple terms, 'out' is a field (i.e. an object) in class 'System' of type 'PrintStream'.

Answer (score 0):

Out is the static reference variable in class System and is of PrintStream(class) type.